# Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlrd

I am having an issue using read_excel on .xlsx files while using a for loop to go through the directory. When doing the following:

```py
df1 = pd.read_excel('***.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('***.xlsx')

df = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

I have no issues. But when I try reading the same files in my loop:

```py
directories_to_check = [
        "C:\\Users\\***"
        ]
files = []
for directory in directories_to_check:
    directories = [d for d in listdir(directory) if isdir(join(directory,d))]
    print(directories)
    for root in directories:
        path = join(directory,root)
        print(path)
        for file in listdir(path):
            print(file)
            if file[0:5].lower() == 'name':
                files.append(join(directory,root,file))
            else:
                files.append(join(directory,root,file))

for filetoopen in files:
    print(filetoopen)
    df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(filetoopen, header=1)], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/***/Sample.py", line 30, in <module>
    df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(filetoopen, header=1)], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
  File "C:\Users\***\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 208, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\***\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 310, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\***\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 819, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "C:\Users\***\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 21, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\***\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 359, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\***\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 36, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\***\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 157, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "C:\Users\***\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 92, in open_workbook_xls
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
  File "C:\Users\***\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1278, in getbof
    bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
  File "C:\Users\***\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1272, in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'C:\\Users'
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What is the result of `print(filetopopen)` before you get the error?

Comment: It prints the file locations of both .xlsx files, along with .txt and .py files that are also in that folder.

Comment: Please provide the exact value before the error

Comment: C:\Users\***.xlsx

C:\Users\***.xlsx

C:\Users\***.txt

This is all it says before the error

Comment: So it fails when reading a text file? I'm not surprised `pd.read_excel` fails! Try filtering out non-.xlsx files

Comment: I was creating a txt file when running the code. Taking that out, and any txt files in the folder, I still get a similar error, this time it prints out this: 
C:\Users.xlsx C:\Users.xlsx C:\Users.py, and gives the following error:


 xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\r\n\r\nimpo'

Comment: Look! The last file it's trying to process is .py! I.e. NOT AN EXCEL FILE